# When i redirect to the previous route some information don't appear

Tags: python, html, flask

Now, I'm rendering books information where I allow the user to add comments to any book when the user click at "add comment" button at book route they redirect to addcomment route, and "comment.html" appear where they can add comments and see previous comments of other users. However, when I click at "add comment" button at book route I can add my comment and see previous comments, but when I post my comment when I am at addcomment route and redirect to the same route(addcomment) the previous comments don't appear

Here is my python code

```
@app.route("/addcomment", methods=  ["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def addcomment():

  global book
  book = request.args.get("book")
  comments = db.execute("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE book_id=? ORDER BY Timestamp DESC",book)
  return render_template 
("comment.html", comments=comments)

@app.route("/comment", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def comment():

  comment = request.args.get("comment")
  if request.method == "GET":
   print(session["user_id"])
   print(book)
   id = session["user_id"]
   print(id)
   user = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=?", id)
   db.execute("INSERT INTO comment (comment, user,book_id) VALUES(?, ?,?)",comment, user[0]["username"],book)
   return redirect (url_for("addcomment"))
```

And here is comment.html

```
<div class="container">

<form action="/comment" method="get">
<div class="row bootstrap snippets bootdeys">
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
    <div class="comment-wrapper">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Comment panel
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="write a comment..." rows="3"></textarea>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Post</button>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <hr>
                {% for comments in comments %}
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <li class="media">
                        <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                            <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle">
                        </a>

                        <div class="media-body">
                            <span class="text-muted pull-right">
                                <small class="text-muted">30 min ago</small>
                            </span>
                            <strong class="text-success">{{comments.user}}</strong>
                            <p>
                              {{comments.comment}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>


                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your python code.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't notice

Comment: Try adding `db.commit()` on the line after you insert. This will commit the changes to the database so they should show up later.

Comment: I got an attribute error that says "AtrributError: 'SQL' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: What is `db` defined as?

Comment: db = SQL("sqlite:///library.db")

Comment: What library is that?